# KSQL stream from Kafka Topic Maintain same partition values

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am creating a ksql stream from kafka topic. Source topic has 50 partitions, and target stream also has 50 partitions, But the issue is  source partition 1 is going to random partition in the target stream ( example partition 10).

Schema:
CREATE STREAM SCHEMA_BASE (
ID VARCHAR,
Timestamp VARCHAR,
CITY VARCHAR,
Partition INTEGER) WITH (
KAFKA_TOPIC = 'SPARK_EVENTS',
VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON',
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS''Z''',
TIMESTAMP = 'Timestamp'
);

Stream : CREATE STREAM spark_event_streams as
SELECT
ID,
Timestamp,
CITY,
Partition
FROM
SCHEMA_BASE
PARTITION BY Partition;

Is there a way I can force the target stream to use exact partitioning??

Comment: Did you use custom partioner while producing your data into the main stream? What is the keys in SPARK_EVENTS topic? Seems your main stream is not partioned by PARTITION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom partitioning is not supported in ksqlDB, and ksqlDB always uses the default partitioner, that implement a round-robin strategy if the message key is `null`.

I filed https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/7984 to maybe extend ksqlDB with a new feature.